# Manipular um objeto que está presente dentro de um ArrayList

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Preciso fazer algumas operações de análise combinatória com informações presentes em objetos, porém não sei extraí-las do `ArrayList`.
Preciso retirar o conteúdo presente na variável prioridade e ausência de cada um dos objetos, caso houver uma maneira mais fácil de fazer, não vejo problema, pode falar, minha meta é fazer isso funcionar. Obrigado desde já.

Classe `Professor`:

```
package horariosprofessores;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Professor {
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private String[] materia;
    private Integer[] ausencia;
    private Integer prioridade;

    public Professor(Integer id, String nome, String[] materia, Integer[] ausencia) {
        //0 SEG, 1 TER, 2 QUAR, 3 QUIN, 4 SEX, 5 SAB
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ausencia = ausencia;
        this.materia = materia;
        this.prioridade = ausencia.length;
    }

    public Professor(Integer id, String nome, String[] materia) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.materia = materia;
        this.prioridade = 0;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String[] getMateria() {
        return materia;
    }

    public void setMateria(String[] materia) {
        this.materia = materia;
    }

    public Integer[] getAusencia() {
        return ausencia;
    }

    public void setAusencia(Integer[] ausencia) {
        this.ausencia = ausencia;
    }

    public Integer getPrioridade() {
        return prioridade;
    }

    public void setPrioridade(Integer prioridade) {
        this.prioridade = prioridade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (ausencia != null)
        return "Professor [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", materia=" + Arrays.toString(materia) + ", ausencia="
                + Arrays.toString(ausencia) + ", prioridade=" + prioridade + "]";
        else
            return "Professor [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", materia=" + Arrays.toString(materia) + ", prioridade=" + prioridade + "]";
    }
}
```

Classe `Horarios`:

```
package horariosprofessores;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Horarios {
    private ArrayList professores;

    public Horarios(ArrayList professores) {
        this.professores = professores;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return professores.toString();
    }

    public void verificaMatriz() {

    }
}
```

Classe `Programa`:

```
package horariosprofessores;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Professor p1 = new Professor(1,"Caceraghi", new String[]{"Algoritmos","Ling. Programação"}, new Integer[]{1,3});
        Professor p2 = new Professor(2,"Modesto", new String[]{"Inglês"});
        Professor p3 = new Professor(3,"Fernanda", new String[]{"Sistemas Computacionais"});

        Horarios horarios = new Horarios(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3)));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Uma vez que você já está usando `List`, então é melhor deixar o uso direto de arrays para lá onde possível.
2. Uma vez que você já está construindo os seus objetos com todos os seus atributos preenchidos, costuma ser boa ideia dispensar-se os setters.
3. Uma vez que você já teria dispensado os setters, evitar `null`s ao usar-se tipos primitivos e usar o modificador `final` é uma boa ideia.
4. Onde o tipo não é primitivo, rejeitar `null`s com uma exceção é uma boa ideia.
5. Nomes de classes devem estar no singular, então use `Horario` ao invés de `Horarios`.
6. Você pode chamar o construtor de `ArrayList`, mas não declare variáveis cujo tipo é `ArrayList`, e sim declare como `List`. O motivo disso é para poder interoperar com outras implementações de `List` que não é `Arraylist`, tal como por exemplo, as que são retornadas por `Arrays.asList(...)`, `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` ou `List.of(...)`, ou mesmo `LinkedList`. Acredito ter sido devido a esse problema que você tentou usar `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList`, o que é uma gambiarra.
7. Para representar dias da semana, use o [enum `DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).
8. Conjuntos de elementos que são `enum`s (no caso, o dia-da-semana) são representados por `EnumSet`s.

Seu código fica assim:

```
package horariosprofessores;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Professor {
    private final int id;
    private final String nome;
    private final List<String> materias;
    private final Set<DayOfWeek> ausencias;
    private final int prioridade;

    public Professor(
            int id,
            String nome,
            List<String> materias,
            Set<DayOfWeek> ausencias)
    {
        if (nome == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (materias == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (ausencias == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ausencias = ausencias;
        this.materias = materias;
        this.prioridade = ausencias.size();
    }

    public Professor(
            int id,
            String nome,
            List<String> materias)
    {
        this(id, nome, materias, EnumSet.noneOf(DayOfWeek.class));
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public List<String> getMaterias() {
        return materias;
    }

    public Set<DayOfWeek> getAusencias() {
        return ausencias;
    }

    public int getPrioridade() {
        return prioridade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Professor"
                + " [id=" + id
                + ", nome=" + nome
                + ", materias=" + materias
                + ", ausencias=" + ausencias
                + ", prioridade=" + prioridade
                + "]";
    }
}
```

```
package horariosprofessores;

import java.util.List;

public class Horario {
    private final List<Professor> professores;

    public Horario(List<Professor> professores) {
        if (professores == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.professores = professores;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return professores.toString();
    }

    public void verificaMatriz() {

    }
}
```

```
package horariosprofessores;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Professor p1 = new Professor(1, "Caceraghi",
                Arrays.asList("Algoritmos", "Ling. Programação"),
                EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY));

        Professor p2 = new Professor(2, "Modesto",
                Arrays.asList("Inglês"));

        Professor p3 = new Professor(3, "Fernanda",
                Arrays.asList("Sistemas Computacionais"));

        Horario horarios = new Horario(Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3));
    }
}
```

Se você estiver usando o Java 9 ou superior, poderá trocar o `Arrays.asList(...)` por `List.of(...)`, que é mais simples e mais seguro.

Para extrair a informação do `List` (dentro da classe `Horario`), você pode iterar eles, utilizar stream ou acessá-los diretamente:

```
// Iterando.
for (Professor p : professores) {
    System.out.println(p);
}

// Com stream.
professores.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

// Acessando diretamente o terceiro professor (índice 2, porque o primeiro é 0).
Professor pa = professores.get(2);
```

Portanto, você pode fazer isso:

```
for (Professor p : professores) {
    // Faz o que quiser com p aqui dentro.
    System.out.println(p.getId() + ": " + p.getPrioridade() + " - " + p.getAusencias());
}
```

No entanto, para ser sincero, não acredito que uma boa modelagem para a classe `Horario` realmente vá evoluir por esse caminho, mas aí isso já seria assunto para uma outra questão.

Comment: Agradeço muito por sua ajuda, ainda sou meio iniciante na linguagem, estudo por 6 meses apenas, vou estudar o seu código e tentar melhorar mais os meus. Se você tiver tempo, poderia me explicar, qual a melhor maneira de evoluir minha classe Horario?